# laravel relationship without morphing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an existing DB that I need to use (without modifying) for a project using laravel.

There's an `Accounts` table, a `Vendor` table, and a `Contacts` table. `Contacts` can belong to either an `Account` or a `Vendor`, in a `belongTo`/`hasMany` relationship.

The `Contacts` table has an `Owner` column that keys to the primary key of either the `Accounts` or `Vendor` table.

As I understand it the "right" way to do this in the laravel world is using morphing, where you'd add `contactable_id` and `contactable_type` columns in the `Contacts` table, and go from there.

However, since I can't modify the DB, I need a way to work using the existing relationship.

I can do something sort of hackish by adding a method to the `Contact` class like this:

```
public static function account_contacts()
{
    return DB::table('Contacts')
        ->join('Accounts', 'Contacts.Owner', '=', 'Accounts.ID');
}
```

However this returns an array of arrays instead of `Contact` objects.

Is there a way to get actual `Contact` objects back, or to create the relationship without using morphing?

EDIT: sorry for the lack of clarity in what I need. I just want to get all `Account`::`Contacts` or all `Vendor`::`Contacts` as an array of `Contacts` so I can iterate them using them as `Contact` models, instead of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question (that is, converting a plain array into an Eloquent model), you could do:

```
$ids = DB:table('Contacts')
           ->join('Accounts', 'Contacts.Owner', '=', 'Accounts.ID')
           ->forPage($pageNumber, $totalPerPage)
           ->pluck('id');

return Contact::findMany($ids);
```

Comment: @alejandro-- that looks perfect. Is it paginatible?

Answer (score 0):

Both `belongsTo` and `hasMany` second parameter is the foreign key, which you can change. Also you can add a `where` condition to it *- if it's necessary, you can leave `where` condition, if there isn't such a field, and one `Contact` only belongs to one model.*

If I understand your question correctly, you can setup your relations forexample for **Accounts** model:

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Contact', 'Owner')->where('type', 'accounts');
}
```

For **Vendor** model:

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Contact', 'Owner')->where('type', 'vendor');
}
```

Comment: But as I think it's strange if there is no type, just an `Owner` field, because the two other table could have the same `id`s. So when you make a query for an `Account` contacts, you can get back some `Vendor`'s contacts at first.